# scrolling a div in angular 4 on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want the contents of a div to scroll to left on click of a button and right on click of another button.

ScrollLeft does'nt seem to work..

html

```
<button id="Left" (click)="leftScroll()">Left</button>       
<div id="myDiagramDiv1" style=" overflow: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;"></div>
<button id="right" (click)="rightScroll()">Right</button>
```

code

```
export class ComponentViewPage implements OnInit {

   leftScroll() {     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('myDiagramDiv1').animate({
            scrollLeft: "+=200px"
        }, "slow");       
    }    

    rightScroll() {     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('myDiagramDiv1').animate({
            scrollLeft: "-=200px"
        }, "slow");       
    }    
}
```

Comment: add code snippet here...

Comment: you did not close `div` with `</div>`

Comment: marginLeft is working but not scrollleft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use jquery, you have to inistall it:

1- inistall jquery

```
npm i jquery --save
```

2- import it into angular.json

```
node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
```

3- use it into component

```
import * as JQuery from "jquery";
const $ = JQuery.default;
```

see live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffzzm9

Answer (score 0):

try into HTML

```
<div #list [scrollTop]="list.scrollHeight"></div>
```

In Component
define id into html `id="scrollId"`

```
const element = document.querySelector('#scrollId');
element.scrollIntoView();
```

you can use `document.getElementById` if `querySelector` isn't working for you.